# Python Discord bot ! command permissions

Tags: python, discord

I was able to get a Discord bot up and running and have a few commands. One of the commands I have is an "!live" command that I can use to make the bot say "@here I'm live right now - urlhere"

How do I go about making the bot check user permissions so not just anyone can use the command?

This is the code I currently have. All it does is reply when a user uses the command "!live"

```
    if p_message == "!live":
        return "I'm live on Twitch - urlhere"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For future questions, [please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [look for existing Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D+discord+command+permissions) before asking, including by [using external search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+python+discord+command+permissions). Aside from that, please try to keep *focused* on *one specific* question when asking. If the question is about how to control permissions for a command, then it is *not also* about the code used to identify the command.

Comment: That said, when using any new third-party library, it is a good idea to work through the documentation. discord.py (either in its original form or the rewrite) does not expect you to implement command prefixes yourself, and it offers [quite a few resources up front](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 1):

Use the actual prefix function that comes with discord.py. I haven't done discord bots in a long time but I can contribute to this.

For example, initiating the prefix is easy.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ">")
```

The client is the actual bot in the discord, and it has a prefix. (In this case, I set it to >)

Now how to define a function.
The basic function has this syntax:

```
@client.command()

async def commmandName(ctx, otherparameters):
    pass
```

If you want a function with permissions,

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles = True) //the permissions

async def function(ctx):
    pass
```

By the way, ctx means context. If you want the author of the message,

```
ctx.author
```

If channel,

```
ctx.channel
```

and such.

It can also be used in replies,

```
await ctx.reply
```

When you want to send a packet to the discord servers, use

```
await yourFunction
```

Await just makes it less likely for your program to return errors and stuff to not work.

For further information on command making you can refer to the docs

[How to make an efficient command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html)